# Accepting a popup with Python in Microsoft Project

Tags: python, ms-project

My current code is

```
mppApp = Dispatch("MSProject.Application")
try:
    mppApp.FileOpen(fileName)
    mppDoc = mppApp.ActiveProject
    core_props = mppDoc.BuiltinDocumentProperties

    for prop_name, core_prop_name in _CORE_PROPERTIES.iteritems():
        try:
            metadata[prop_name] = core_props(core_prop_name).Value
        except:
            metadata[prop_name] = ""

    for key in ['created', 'modified', 'printed']:
        if key in metadata and metadata[key]!="":
           metadata[key] = strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", gmtime(int(metadata[key])))

    for prop_name, core_prop_name in _CORE_PROPERTIES.iteritems():
        print core_prop_name, "=", metadata[prop_name]

except:
    print fileName, "could not be opened"
mppApp.Quit(SaveChanges=0)
time.sleep(.1)
```

When I open a .mpp file with this automated python code, I have a popup that says

"There are multiple lines of text in the existing note. Multiple lines of text can only be entered using the Notes tab of the Task Information dialog box. If you change the note in the table, all lines of text except the first line, and all formatting, will be removed. Do you want to change the note in the table anyway? Click Yes to change the note in the table. Click No to discard the change you just made and to open the Task Information dialog box"

This pop-up doesn't appear if I quit after I dispatch the application, open the file, and set the doc to the active project. As soon as I grab the BuiltinDocumentProperties and try to quit, the pop-up appears. I was wondering if there was a way to accept this pop-up with python. If I try to quit with the pop-up there, I get a pywintypes.com_error saying that the Call was rejected by callee.

If I manually accept the pop-up and then call the quit line again, it will close the Microsoft Project application.

Comment: I just found out that as soon as I assign the BuiltinDocumentProperties, it gives me the pop-up. That would be why my code doesn't receive any of the information.

I'm not sure if this is the way I want to go, but it would be nice to know how to accept/dismiss the pop-up for further notice.

Comment: Upon further studying, I found out that the Notes field, which can hold more than 256 characters also doubles as the Comments in the BuiltinDocumentProperties. So, this can break the assignment from the BIDP. If I can figure out how to accept the pop-up, I can then check for the error and then have the user check the details manually.